# What is the easiest reliable way to host a HTTPS enabled static page on a domain I own

Tags: web-hosting, https

I'm looking for a simple & reliable way to host a HTTPS enabled static page on a domain I own. The fist thing that came to mind was S3 static website hosting but there seems to be no way to enable HTTPS for that.

What other alternatives are there?

Comment: You're right Amazon doesn't support HTTPS. There isn't really an 'easy' way to do it.

Since you own the domain you are going to have to provide your own certificate. A self-signed one is the easy way to go, but that will cause the browser warning to pop up about a potentially unsafe site. How are you hosting your domain?

Comment: The website is not online at the moment.. I'm pretty sure there must be a smarter way to do this other than getting and managing a VPS just to serve some static HTML over HTTPS...

Comment: You will require dedicated ip to install an SSL certificate and i don't think it who important that single static page for you to invest in dedicated ip, server and ssl certificate it-self.

Answer (score 1):

SSL certificates are issued to the domain it then requires installing via your host or yourself. Shared hosting, the host would do the install for you since you don't normally have the option to do so. On unmanaged services such as dedicated, vps and instances on Amazon you are expected to install software yourself.

Valid SSL certificates are issued by trusted ca companies these normally cost money, once you paid they issue you several unique files this are installed within the OS and not the top level... hence you won't the option since this is your responsibility as a unmanaged service.

So because they are issued to the domain and not the host and require installing is among many reasons they do not provide SSL on hosting. You will need to use a instance and install the ssl, or use a managed vps service or shared hosting if you don't want to install yourself.

Comment: I'm aware of how SSL certificate work and what they involve. There are "cloud" services like the Google App Engine or CloudFlare that allow you to bring your own certificate to the service. None of those services however are primarily intended for static files hosting, so I was wondering if there is another service that is.

Comment: The problem is using custom domains, CDN based on the cloud have their own SSL but these are normally provided on their own wildcard of their domain. As soon as you want to issue your own then it needs to be done on the OS level. I understand what your after but its not as simple as you want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options that provide simple static hosting + SSL, some are:

- [Firebase Hosting](https://www.firebase.com/hosting.html)
- [Parse](https://parse.com/docs/hosting_guide)
- [Divshot](http://www.divshot.com/)
- [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/)

You could also use something like Heroku or S3. These all have varying degrees of complexity (particularly if you want SSL) and cost, although in most cases if you're just doing static asset hosing you'd be better off choosing something other than S3 for ease of use and cost.

Since I work at Firebase, I'll add that Firebase Hosting supports non-[SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) SSL (with automatic certificate provisioning), custom domains (even naked domains), is backed by a CDN and has one click deploys and rollbacks.

Comment: GitHub Pages does NOT support custom domain https